# jquery validator not working for require from group?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/" >
    <input type="text"   name="number0" class="form-control">
    <input type="text"  name="amount0"  class="form-control send">
    <input type="text"  name="operator0" class="form-control ">
    <select id="bundle0" name="bundle" class="bundle send" >
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text"   name="number1" class="form-control">
    <input type="text"  name="amount1"  class="form-control send">
    <input type="text"  name="operator1" class="form-control ">
    <select id="bundle" name="bundle2" class="bundle send" >
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </select>
    ........//upto n numbers
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JQUERY VALIDATOR**

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules : {
        amount0: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".send"]
        },
        bundle0: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".send"]
        },
        operator0:"required"
    }
});
```

**issues:**

1) require from group not working for select box. i want either selectbox            for bundle or amount to be filled

2) how to do validation for all the fileds operator0,operator1 etc..

Comment: Try <Select required >

Comment: 1) Simply ensure that at least one input or select is completed.2)There is not clear rules for option validation, maybe you can try `jQuery.validator.addMethod`, refer to https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Comment: @JiangangXiong, your comment is complete nonsense.   The plugin has no problem validating `select` elements that are properly constructed.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) require from group not working for select box.

You don't even have the `select` box properly declared in your `rules` object.  The rules are declared based on the `name`, not the `id`.

Additionally, to validate a `select` element with this plugin, the first option **must** contain a `value=''` attribute.  Notice that the value is an empty string.  Otherwise, the default value is the content between the `<option></option>` tags.  Since your value is not empty, the rule is always immediately satisfied before making a selection.

```
<select id="bundle0" name="bundle" class="bundle send">
    <option value=''>please choose</option>
    <option>a</option> <!-- // value defaults to "a" //-->
    ....
```